# Showing echo message when user failed login

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to get this done. First, let's take a look at my code:

```
<?php 
$key = "key"; 
if ($_POST['token'] != $key) { 
?>
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
<p>Token:<br /><input type="text" name="token" class="token" /></p> 
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Use token" /></p> 
</form> 
<?php 
} else { 
include("inc/fullregister.inc.php");
}
?>
```

How can I show an echo message when the user failed this login?

Comment: Maybe change this part: `include("inc/fullregister.inc.php");` to `echo "login failed";` or something like that ?

Comment: You may also need to possibly re-organize your code for clarity and proper condition checking. Is that all the code that you have or is there more to it ?

Comment: `if(condition){ do something } else{ do something else }` not to mention using `isset()` and/or `empty()`.

Comment: The script is basically protecting fullregister.inc.php from people who do not have the code. When the right code is entered, it will show fullregister.inc.php, that all is working but I don't know how to make it so it shows an error when the wrong code is entered.

Comment: no idea. your posted code's probably generating an undefined "something" but you're masking the notice. Plus, if you're trying to check if they've entered the right word as compared and taken from either a file or a database, you need to tell us. Otherwise, this it guesswork.

Comment: that's not my downvote but saying "all those downvotes", why you expecting more than one? lol edit: ah, there's another but again; not mine. probably your question's unclear or another reason; who knows.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This code above is all I have for you. The other codes/database don't have anything to do with this.

Comment: *"it's a normal question"* - [and this is a normal answer...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087745/showing-echo-message-when-user-failed-login#comment48288814_30087745) given your code.

Comment: as I said; your code's generating notices right off the bat and on page load, because you're not checking if the POST array is set or empty or if the submit was clicked. Here: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Notice: Undefined index: token in /home/-/public_html/customerpanel/inc/lockedregister.inc.php on line 3

Comment: there, I knew it. Give me a few minutes; I'll write something up for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of both `isset()` and `empty()` which will prevent notices for undefined index/variables.

I've reformulated your code a tad.

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
<p>Token:<br /><input type="text" name="token" class="token" /></p> 
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Use token" /></p> 
</form> 

<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST['Submit']) ) {

if(!empty($_POST['token']) ){

$key = $_POST['token'];
$secret_key = "key";

if ($key != $secret_key) {
    echo "Wrong key.";
}

else { 
    // include("inc/fullregister.inc.php");
    echo "Check.";
}

    } // brace for if(!empty($_POST['token']) )

else{
    echo "Key is empty.";
}

    } // closing brace for if(isset($_POST['Submit']) )

?>
```

---

Sidenote: Forms do not bear the name attribute, so you can safely remove `name="form"` from it.

Comment: @bemyhero You're welcome ;-) glad I could help, *cheers* and you too.